# Android - Two ContentProviders which one does getContentResolver() retrieve?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-contentprovider

Lets say i have defined two contentProviders in the same Android Manifest and they both are contained in the same package.

When i call: `context.getContentResolver()`

Which ContentProvider will my CRUD operations flow to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ContentResolver is the one that will decide where the operations go.  When you request an operation, the first parameter is a Uri that has an authority and a path in it.  The Resolver matches the authority to a single ContentProver and then issues the calls to that provider

Answer (score 1):

When you run a request on the ContentResolver, you pass in a URI.   This is what determines what contentProvider gets called.